# Trouble with input/output

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have, in my `taskBckg.java` file this line:

```
userInput.askGetInput("There were errors creating the file.  " +
    "Would you like to continue ahead with diagnostics? " +
    "(Type \"y\" or \"yes\", or \"n\" or \"no\".) " +
    "This will only take a minute.");`
```

This call actually goes through another method, and I am not sure yet, but I would like to somehow request a user response through this method (of asking a question, and returning an answer) - any ideas here?

```
// ask question, and return a response...
public String askGetInput(String outText) {
    // Update textArea with question
    writeToTextArea(outText);
    // Wait for the user to respond, and press the submit button
    return uI.getText();
}
```

Not exactly sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29).

E.G.

```
String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainFrame,"Enter some text");
```

But now I look at your code more closely, it seems you need a 'yes/no' answer, which is better suited to a [`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Component,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29).

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, outputMessage);
if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    // ...
```

Both those methods have overloaded arguments, check the JavaDocs for other variants.